# How can I blend up to 3 textures on a polygon without blend maps?

Tags: opengl, java, glsl, lwjgl

For my voxel game I need to blend up to 3 textures in the same polygon.
It would be preferable if I could specify a texture id for each vertex, but other solutions are accepted as well.

Here's an illustration of what I want.
[image: textured triangle]

How can I achieve this type of blending?

Multi texturing with blend maps is *NOT* a solution.
Also please notice that there will be a lot of different textures.

Comment: Wow that's some serious photoshop right here! Seriously though, you might want to take a look at shaders, they seem like your better option.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I've got some pretty decent Adobe skills.

Comment: @KaareZ Lol I may have fixed that for you with GIMP. xD

Comment: Can you define "a lot of different textures" more precisely? There's a fairly straightforward way to support up to about 40, a more expensive way to handle around 256, and more exotic approaches beyond that...

Comment: @DMGregory I think it will be around a 100 textures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In very broad strokes, you can accomplish this by:

- Yes, using shaders
- Binding three textures to the shader program before drawing
- On your polygons, have the usual UV vec2 for each vertex. This is used by any of the textures
- Have another attribute which is "weight of each texture at this vertex". It could be a vec3 or three separate floats. For the illustration above, the weights for the three vertexes would be something like (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1).
- (If you don't want a smooth fade across the whole triangle, maybe a more confined fade-over towards the middle, you could work out a different interpretation of the weighting-triplet)
- In the shader, sample all three textures at the desired UV coordinate, and multiply each one by the corresponding WEIGHT component. Sum them up for the output pixel.

The shader will interpolate the weights across polygon, just like for the UV.

As described here, you'd have to re-set the three textures for every polygon, or at least batch the ones that use the same three textures.

Changing bits of the context (such as texture bindings) might be a performance bottleneck. If so, an optimization is to use a "Texture Atlas", where your textures are tiled together into one bigger texture. Then you just keep that one, no rebinding.

Then some attributes on each vertex would need to specify, "Within the texture atlas, which tile corresponds to textures 1, 2, and 3.". These would have to be the same for all three vertices of each triangle.

(If you're not already using shaders, this might seem like a steep set of hurdles. But shaders are awesome, so go for it!)